# Deeply nested Angular routes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

A the root of my app I have a "demo" route to a module that handles all the demos on the site:

```
{
  path: 'demo',
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  loadChildren: './demo/demo.module#DemoModule'
}
```

Then, in the demo module's routing module I have all the demos, some of which are also modules, such as

```
{
  path: 'splitviews',
  loadChildren: './splitviews/splitviews.module#SplitviewsModule'
}
```

Which is a module of demos of types of "Splitviews", components with 2 named route outlets: 1 for the left nav and 1 for the content:

```
<app-header class="site-header"></app-header>

<div class="site-content"></div>
<div [ngClass]="containerType"
    class="splitview-wrapper">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"">
      <router-outlet name="leftnav"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer class="site-footer"></app-footer>
```

So far, this module has routing like this

```
path: 'basic',
component: SplitviewsComponent,
data: {
  containerType: 'container'
},
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LeftnavBasicComponent,
    outlet: 'leftnav'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: Content1Component,
    outlet: 'content'
  }
]
},
```

So now if you went to `/demo/splitviews/basic` you'd see the splitviews component with the header, footer, and the 2 route outlets displaying `LeftnavBasicComponent` and `Content1Component`.

*But* now what I need to do is have the *links* in the `LeftnavBasicComponent` load different content components (e.g. `Content2Component`) inside the router-outlet "content". And I'm not sure how to best configure those sub-routes.

Comment: Why not have a single component for the children with `path: ''` and then have that component import both `LeftnavBasicComponent` and `Content1Component` as child components?

Comment: I want to be able to switch both the left Mac and the content to demo different types of leftnav and content combos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LeftnavBasicComponent** and **Content1Component** as placeholders and then the components you really want to show will be loaded inside them depending on a value you'll pass by url.

Your html will be like below

```
<app-header class="site-header"></app-header>

<div class="site-content"></div>
<div [ngClass]="containerType"
    class="splitview-wrapper">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"">
      <app-leftnav></app-leftnav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <app-content></app-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app-leftnav** and **app-content** are respectively the selectors of **LeftnavBasicComponent** and **Content1Component**.

The routing module will simply look like below:

```
{
path: 'basic/:leftnavtype/:contenttype',
component: SplitviewsComponent,
data: {
  containerType: 'container'
}
}
```

Now in the **LeftnavBasicComponent** typescript file we have to take the value of **leftnavtype** from the url and put it in a variable like below:

```
leftNavType: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.leftNavType = params["leftnavtype"];
  });
}
```

And finally in the **LeftnavBasicComponent** html file we show a specific component depending on the **leftNavType** value

```
<app-type-1-left-nav *ngIf="leftNavType==='type1'"></app-type-1-left-nav>
<app-type-2-left-nav *ngIf="leftNavType==='type2'"></app-type-2-left-nav>
```

The same will be done for the **content** placeholder.

After doing so, if you call /demo/splitviews/basic/type1/content3, the type1 component will be loaded in the left nav placeholder and the content3 component will be loaded in the content placeholder, **and you can then generate the link you want in the navigation part to load a specific component in the content part.**

It may not be the perfect solution, but it works in your case.

And if there is only few cases, **I suggest simply creating a route for each one**, both solutions work depending on your needs.

Happy to clarify more if needed!